# wait for Future in for loop

Tags: sql, for-loop, dart, wait, future

I'm having a future which is a result of an sql query, in it I'm looping over each returned row to add it to a list with a map to encode it to a json format later.
In this loop I'm executing another query depending on the result in each row of the outer query and add those rows again to a map.

```
Future<Results> mysqlAllTags = mysqlCon.query(query).then((results){
  // Make new list as a part of the JsonObject
  json.tags = new List();
  // Loop throught the row of the result from Mysql data
  return results.forEach((row){
    // Create Map to put the word, value, rating and id into the JsonObject
    Map data = new Map();

    // Put the Mysql data into the Map
    data["word"] = row.word.toString();
    data["value"] = row.value.toString();
    data["rating"] = row.rating.toString();
    data["id_tag"] = row.id_tag.toString();
    data["replacing"] = null;
    
    // Add the Map to the userPages list
    json.tags.add(data);
  }).then((e){
    for(var tag in json.tags){
      //Map dataReplacing = getReplacing(userId, row.id_tag.toString());
      String replacingTags = getReplacingSQL(tag['id_tag'].toString());
      mysqlCon.query(replacingTags).then((result){
        result.forEach((row1){
          Map map = new Map();
         
          map["word"] = row1.word.toString();
          map["value"] = row1.value.toString();
          map["id_tag"] = row1.id_replacing_tag.toString();
          tag["replacing"] = map;
        }).then((e){
          print("then inner for called");
          return null;
        });
        print("then inner for called");
        return null;
      });
    }
    
    print("outer for returned");
    // Send the data in UTF8 to the client 
    result = Helpers.formatJsonAndEncodeUtf8('OK', session:_session, data: [json]);
    
    return null;
  }).catchError((error){
     result = Helpers.formatJsonAndEncodeUtf8('ERROR 856284555 (Could not load tags)', session:_session);
  });
}).catchError((error){
  result = Helpers.formatJsonAndEncodeUtf8('ERROR 2346644555 (Could not load tags)', session:_session);
});
    
return Future.wait([mysqlAllTags]).then((e){
  print("future returned");
  return result;
});
```

The result looks like this:

> outer for returned
>
> === TO CLIENT ===
>
> {"status":[{"message":"OK","csrfToken":"99"}],"data":[{"tags":[{"word":"Melon","value":"11.0","rating":"1","id_tag":"37","replacing":null},........}]}
>
> =================
>
> future returned
>
> then inner for called
>
> then inner for called
>
> then inner for called
>
> then inner for called
>
> then inner for called
>
> then inner for called
>
> then inner for called
>
> then inner for called

How can I wait until all Futures in my for loop are finished?

Comment: Have you considered using async/await. This makes it a lot easier to reason about the code.

Comment: You should format your code using `dartfmt` it would be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding the result declaration in the `Future.wait(futures).then()` function. Thank you Günter Zöchbauer for your input.

```
Future<Results> mysqlAllTags = mysqlCon.query(query).then((results){
  // Make new list as a part of the JsonObject
  json.tags = new List();
  // Loop throught the row of the result from Mysql data
  return results.forEach((row){
  // Create Map to put the word, value, rating and id into the JsonObject
  Map data = new Map();

  // Put the Mysql data into the Map
  data["word"] = row.word.toString();
  data["value"] = row.value.toString();
  data["rating"] = row.rating.toString();
  data["id_tag"] = row.id_tag.toString();
  data["replacing"] = null;

  // Add the Map to the userPages list
  json.tags.add(data);
}).then((e){
  var futures = []; // added
  for(var tag in json.tags){
    print("row ");
    print(json.tags);
    //Map dataReplacing = getReplacing(userId, row.id_tag.toString());
    String replacingTags = getReplacingSQL(tag['id_tag'].toString());

    // added `futures.add(...)`
    futures.add(mysqlCon.query(replacingTags).then((result) { 
      result.forEach((row1){
        Map map = new Map();

        map["word"] = row1.word.toString();
        map["value"] = row1.value.toString();
        map["id_tag"] = row1.id_replacing_tag.toString();
        tag["replacing"] = map;
      }).then((e){
        print("then inner for called");
        return null;
      });
      print("then inner for called");
      return null;
    }));
  }

  print("outer for returned");
  // Send the data in UTF8 to the client 

    return Future.wait(futures).then((e){
      result = Helpers.formatJsonAndEncodeUtf8('OK', session:_session, data: [json]);
    }); // added
  }).catchError((error){
     result = Helpers.formatJsonAndEncodeUtf8('ERROR 856284555 (Could not load tags)', session:_session);
  });
}).catchError((error){
  result = Helpers.formatJsonAndEncodeUtf8('ERROR 2346644555 (Could not load tags)', session:_session);
});

return Future.wait([mysqlAllTags]).then((e){
  print("future returned");
  return result;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fixes all issues, it's not easy to see in such code what exactly returns a future. (I added comments where I added something)

```
Future<Results> mysqlAllTags = mysqlCon.query(query).then((results){
  // Make new list as a part of the JsonObject
  json.tags = new List();
  // Loop throught the row of the result from Mysql data
  return results.forEach((row){
    // Create Map to put the word, value, rating and id into the JsonObject
    Map data = new Map();

    // Put the Mysql data into the Map
    data["word"] = row.word.toString();
    data["value"] = row.value.toString();
    data["rating"] = row.rating.toString();
    data["id_tag"] = row.id_tag.toString();
    data["replacing"] = null;

    // Add the Map to the userPages list
    json.tags.add(data);
  }).then((e){
    var futures = []; // added
    for(var tag in json.tags){
      print("row ");
      print(json.tags);
      //Map dataReplacing = getReplacing(userId, row.id_tag.toString());
      String replacingTags = getReplacingSQL(tag['id_tag'].toString());

      // added `futures.add(...)`
      futures.add(mysqlCon.query(replacingTags).then((result) { 
        result.forEach((row1){
          Map map = new Map();

          map["word"] = row1.word.toString();
          map["value"] = row1.value.toString();
          map["id_tag"] = row1.id_replacing_tag.toString();
          tag["replacing"] = map;
        }).then((e){
          print("then inner for called");
          return null;
        });
        print("then inner for called");
        return null;
      }));
    }

    print("outer for returned");
    // Send the data in UTF8 to the client 
    result = Helpers.formatJsonAndEncodeUtf8('OK', session:_session, data: [json]);

    return Future.wait(futures); // added
  }).catchError((error){
     result = Helpers.formatJsonAndEncodeUtf8('ERROR 856284555 (Could not load tags)', session:_session);
  });
}).catchError((error){
  result = Helpers.formatJsonAndEncodeUtf8('ERROR 2346644555 (Could not load tags)', session:_session);
});

return Future.wait([mysqlAllTags]).then((e){
  print("future returned");
  return result;
});
```

Comment: this solution didn't work, I think because the array can be empty or not completely filled when Future.wait(futures) is called there is nothing to wait for, so it will return